# Very weak wireless connection on Debian live image install

Tags: debian, drivers, wifi, live-usb

I'm having a problem with the wireless connection on a fresh install of Debian 7.4 which I didn't have before, I had Debian installed before and WiFi was working great, the only thing that changed this time is installing it from a [live install image](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/) instead of the [CD/DVD images](https://www.debian.org/CD/).

My wireless card is **Atheros AR5005G**, and [ath5k](https://wiki.debian.org/ath5k) is already installed.

I'm trying to fix this problem and I searched about the issue but everything I found was about increasing `txpower` using `iwconfig` or setting `power` to `off` which is already off in my case.

So what could be the problem:

- I remember that it was working fine on an old Debian distribution which had the [madwifi](http://madwifi-project.org/) driver
- I'm dual booting Debian with Windows and on windows it's working fine
- My laptop connects to the router without any problems
- I had a live USB using the same image which had the same problem
- I didn't have this problem before when I installed from the regular CD/DVD images
- I have to be very close to the router to be able to access the internet
- Pinging the router or any website takes a long time with many lost packets
- 408 (Request Timeout) errors occur while browsing

Running `lspci -v` shows:

```
0a:03.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR2413/AR2414 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5005G(S) 802.11bg] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. Device 0418
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 18
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
```

**Update**:

Here are the `dmesg` related messages:

```
...
[7.485709] ath5k 0000:0a:03.0: registered as 'phy0'
...
[8.429871] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[8.430578] ath5k phy0: Atheros AR2413 chip found (MAC: 0x78, PHY: 0x45)
```

And this is the full output of `dmesg` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LSTmaVuS).

Comment: Can you provide some information regarding your wireless hardware and what userspace tools do you use to connect to WiFi?

Comment: @edvinas.me sorry I forgot about that, I added the wireless card name.

Comment: It worked previously with a Debian 7 installation from a regular CD/DVD image? This installation did not use madifi? Maybe your issue is connected with wrong CRDA (Central Regulatory Database Agent - country-specific settings for wireless) settings. Can you post via pastebin (or similar) related parts of your kernel messages (dmesg)?

Comment: @jofel I added the `dmesg` output to the question, and yes it worked before and it was a new Debian version **7.3** and I don't think it was using `madwifi`, because it's deprecated and replaced by `ath5k`, but it's working fine on Windows now and it worked on an old Debian live cd with madwifi.

Comment: If you know another version is working why don't you install it (or run from a live) and check the differences? If it is only about the driver or there are other settings/apps.

Comment: @Alex the other version is not a live CD, and it has the same driver `ath5k`, I also tried installing madwifi but it requires an older kernel version 2.4

Comment: @Peter and the `other version` isn't weak? If so I would start checking versions, the kernel and its config if available, the driver and all the tools and apps related to the wifi, then their settings. Also logs could show some difference, use something like [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) (some `sed` will be required). If still can't find anything then maybe `debian-user` and `ath5` mailing lists can help